# How do I get the full route path including the parameters from express or extend the request object to do so?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following route in my express (version 4.17.1) API in a postTimecardCompany.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Timecard = require('./../models/timecard');

function postTimecardCompany(server) {
    server.post('/api/v1/timecard/:userId', (req, res) => {    
        // Insert timecard data into the database
        Timecard.create(data, (error, result) => {
            // Check for errors
            if (error) {
                res.status(500).end();
                return;
            }
            
            // Respond
            res.status(200).send({timecardId: result._id});
        });
    });
}

module.exports = postTimecardCompany;
```

The route (among other routes) is loaded via the following mechanism by server.js file:

```
[   
    'postTimecardCompany',
    'anotherRoute',
    'someOtherRoute',
    'andSoOn...'
].map((route) => {
    require('./core/routes/' + route + '.js').call(null, server)
});
```

I have a middleware (in server.js file) where I check which route is being called.

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
    // If route is "/api/v1/timecard/:userId" do something
});
```

I have found various solutions which do nearly what I am looking for, but not exactly.
For example, if I post to the route with a data parameter userId value of "123f9b" then req.originalUrl gives an output of "/api/v1/timecard/123f9b."

What i'm looking to get is the original route path with the parameters in it so for a request of "/api/v1/timecard/123f9b" it would be: "/api/v1/timecard/:userId."

How do I get this functionality in express or extend express to get the original route path with parameters in the request object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use from your approach, it's is impossible, after that your approach is not standard in `express` check the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html), if you want get routes in a middleware you should try like this:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()
const postTimecardCompany = require('./routes/postTimecardCompany.js')// don't use map()
server.use("/",postTimecardCompany)//use the routes
server.listen(6565,()=>console.log(`Listening to PORT 6565`))
```

routes of **postTimecardCompany.js**

use `Router` of express and export router, and you can use middleware before each route you want, there are many ways to use middleware in routes, check the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const middleware = require('../middleware');//require middlewares

router.post("/api/v1/timecard/:userId", middleware,(req, res) => {
  // Insert timecard data into the database
  console.log(req.route.path);
});
module.exports = router;
```

**middleware.js**

```
module.exports = ((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.route.path);
    next()
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined" when console logging req.route.path. Express version is 4.17.1.

Comment: can you add route file completely?because I never seen router in a function

Comment: I added most of the route file that I was comfortable with adding. I also added the mechanism by which the route is loaded into the server. I suspect the later is probably the culprit.